# Issues running jest tests from Stackblitz

Tags: jestjs, stackblitz

I am having difficulties running my jest tests from stackblitz.

I have configured a start command in `.stackblitzrc` but my tests are  not run...

My jest config is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'json'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom', 'src/setupTests.ts'],
};
```

Here is the stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-74twff

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the template you started out with doesn't look like it supports Web Containers. I'm not sure if there's a way to migrate it or not. In order to use Web Containers, you start with a Node-based template and add functionality to that.

Below is a sample I put together that should get you working. You should be able to fork this and add your application's files or use it as a reference when building a new Stackblitz project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-5-react-starter-ahpjpn?file=src/app.test.tsx

Comment: I've got a similar question to balteo - I'm trying to run a basic jest test in StackBlitz. I set up a Node project and added some app files based on create-react-app. When I run a test I get a "RangeError". I checked your StackBlitz and it seems you ran an eject - is that really needed? What actual config change did you make from the default to make the test work? Here's my stackblitz - you can run `npm test` to see the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-gaygkf?file=src/demo.test.tsx

Comment: Something changed with SB and the behavior of the web containers changed.